# How to avoid BeautifulSoup: Value Error: No tables found?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I wanted to extract a table from a website with BeautifulSoup. First, I extracted the DAX year end courses (Name of the element "HistKurseYear"). This worked perfectly fine. Then I tried to extract the year end courses from Adidas (Name of the element "HistKurseYear"), which gave me the `ValueError: No tables found`. However, in Excel it was possible to retrieve the table.

```
page_Ad = requests.get(
    "https://www.boerse.de/historische-kurse/Adidas-Aktie/DE000A1EWWW0")
soup_Ad = BeautifulSoup(page_Ad.content, 'html.parser')


element_Ad = soup_Ad.find(id='histKurseYear')

df_Adidas = pd.read_html(str(element_Ad))[0]
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-03cb2123ccf1> in <module>
----> 1 df_Adidas = pd.read_html(str(element_Ad))[0]

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pandas/io/html.py in _parse_tables(self, doc, match, attrs)
    567 
    568         if not tables:
--> 569             raise ValueError("No tables found")
    570 
    571         result = []

ValueError: No tables found
```

Additionally I tried another table from the website the end courses on a monthly basis - worked. Furthermore in Excel it was possible to retrieve the table.

What can I do to get the desired table?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is, that there is no element with such `id`, there is only a `<div>` with a `class` named like `histKurseYear` and that is why `pandas` could not  find any from your `None` string.

---

Just pick the table directly by its index from list of dataframes that is created by [`pandas.read_html()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

```
pd.read_html('https://www.boerse.de/historische-kurse/Adidas-Aktie/DE000A1EWWW0')[4]
```

Or try to match with a string in the table:

```
pd.read_html('https://www.boerse.de/historische-kurse/Adidas-Aktie/DE000A1EWWW0', match='Jahr')[0]
```